# BigNumber multiplying decimal values in ethers

Tags: javascript, web3js, ethers.js, bignum

I want to do math - `100000 * 1.004` by using `BigNumber` values. The biggest problem here is that `1.004` is a float and BigNumber does not accept it. I am using ethers.js library for it.

I tried to use `parseUnits("1.004", 18)`. I am using 18 because basically I am operating on stable coins prices.

I get `BigNumber { value: "1004000000000000000" }` from it.
To do the math I have to parse `100000` also so I do it in the same way - `parseUnits("100000", 18)`. After that I just do `parseUnits("1.004", 18).mul(parseUnits("100000", 18))` to multiply them and I get `BigNumber { value: "100400000000000000000000000000000000000000" }`.

When I use `formatUnits()` method to get a number back I get `100400000000000000000000.0` where correct value should be `100000 * 1.004 = 100400`.

What is the correct way of doing calculations like that by using the ethers.js library?

Comment: `parseUnits("100000", 18)` gives you a big number value of 100000 times 10 to the 18th power. You then multiply that by 1.004 times 10 to the 18th power. That's where all the zeros are coming from.

Comment: @Pointy yes that's right but what if I would like to do calculation like:
100000 * 0.9998 * 1.0004. I do `BigNumber.from(100000).mul(ethers.utils.parseUnits("1.0004", 18)).mul(ethers.utils.parseUnits("0.9998", 18))` and I get `BigNumber { value: "100019992000000000000000000000000000000000" }` where I want to get `100019.992`

Comment: I would perform the multiplication of 100000 and 1.0004 *before* scaling out with 18 extra digits.

Comment: @Pointy yes that's right but I use `BigNumber` values because of safety reasons. I get `1.0004` and `0.9998` values from endpoints so I want to convert them into `BigNumber` and do operations on `BigNumber` values.

Comment: I mean make BigNumber instances for 100000 and 1.004, then do the `.mul()` between those, and then scale up the result.

Comment: You might like my library that does most of this and is way faster than most of the bignumber libraries. I wrote this specifically for dealing with large crypto values: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bigint-money

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally decided to use `bignumber.js` library for that. `ethers.js` does not support float values with decimals when `bignumber.js` does it perfectly without any formatting.

Answer (score 2):

We faced the same exact issue and we were able to solve it by just multiplying that floated number by one big number and dividing it back by one big number too, this utility class in typescript demonstrates that all:

```
import { BigNumber, utils } from "ethers";

export class BigNumberUtils {
    protected oneBN: BigNumber = utils.parseUnits("1", 18);
    constructor() {}

    public multiply(
        bn: BigNumber | string,
        number: number,
    ): BigNumber {
        const bnForSure = BigNumber.from(bn);
        const numberBN = utils.parseUnits(number.toString(), 18);

        return bnForSure.mul(numberBN).div(this.oneBN);
    }

    public divide(bn: BigNumber | string, number: number): BigNumber {
        const bnForSure = BigNumber.from(bn);
        const numberBN = utils.parseUnits(number.toString(), 18);

        return bnForSure.div(numberBN).div(this.oneBN);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert BigNumber to float, multiply and then convert the result to BigNumber:

```
import { BigNumber, ethers } from "ethers";

function mulBigNumbers(a: BigNumber, b: BigNumber): BigNumber {
    if (a == null || a.isZero() || b == null || b.isZero()) {
        return BigNumber.from(0);
    }

    const aFloat = parseFloat(ethers.utils.formatEther(a));
    const bFloat = parseFloat(ethers.utils.formatEther(b));

    if (isNaN(aFloat) || isNaN(bFloat)) {
        return BigNumber.from(0);
    }

    const resultFloat = aFloat * bFloat;

    return ethers.utils.parseEther(resultFloat.toFixed(18));
}
```